# Magento 2 addFieldToFilter equal today for datetime field

Tags: magento2, collection, model, filter

I have a model with field in datetime format, i want to filter the field with equal today date like this:

```
$collections = $this->customFactory->create()->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('created_at',date("Y-m-d"));
return $collections->getSize();
```

but it always return **0**

Comment: Check my updated answer will help in your issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
$now = $objDate->timestamp();
$start = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', $now);
$end = date('Y-m-d' . ' 23:59:59', $now);
$collections = $this->customFactory->create()->getCollection();
$collections->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $start, 'to' => $end));
return $collections->getSize();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this code:**

```
$collections = $this->customFactory->create()->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
return $collections->getSize();
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$collections = $this->customFactory->create()->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('created_at',$now->format('Y-m-d'));

return $collections->getSize();
```

Comment: this is not working